# Python Pandas when i try to add a column in an existing dataframe my new column is not correct

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying to get a religion adherence data visulization project done. But on my i am stuck with this problem pls help thank you

```
    x= range(1945,2011,5)
    for i in x:
       df_new= df_new.append(pd.DataFrame({'year':[i]}))
    

    years
0   1945
0   1950
0   1955
0   1960
0   1965
0   1970
0   1975
0   1980
0   1985
0   1990
0   1995
0   2000
0   2005
0   2010
```

this is my dataframe for now and i want to add a column which looks like this :

```
0     1.307603e+08
1     2.941211e+08
2     3.440720e+08
3     4.351231e+08
4     5.146341e+08
5     5.923423e+08
6     6.636743e+08
7     6.471395e+08
8     7.457716e+08
9     9.986003e+08
10    1.153186e+09
11    1.314048e+09
12    1.426454e+09
13    1.555483e+09
```

when i add them up like that

```
a=df.groupby(['year'],as_index=False)['islam'].sum()
b=a['islam']
df_new.insert(1,'islam',b)
```

the dataframe look like this which is not correct help me pls thank you !

```
    year    islam
0   1945    130760281.0
0   1950    130760281.0
0   1955    130760281.0
0   1960    130760281.0
0   1965    130760281.0
0   1970    130760281.0
0   1975    130760281.0
0   1980    130760281.0
0   1985    130760281.0
0   1990    130760281.0
0   1995    130760281.0
0   2000    130760281.0
0   2005    130760281.0
0   2010    130760281.0
```

df:

```
    year    name    christianity    judaism islam   budism  nonrelig
0   1945    USA 110265118   4641182.0   0.0 1601218 22874544
1   1950    USA 122994019   6090837.0   0.0 0   22568130
2   1955    USA 134001770   5333332.0   0.0 90173   23303540
3   1960    USA 150234347   5500000.0   0.0 2012131 21548225
4   1965    USA 167515758   5600000.0   0.0 1080892 19852362
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1990 1990   WSM 159500  0.0 37.0    15  1200
1991 1995   WSM 161677  0.0 43.0    16  1084
1992 2000   WSM 174600  0.0 50.0    18  1500
1993 2005   WSM 177510  0.0 58.0    18  1525
1994 2010   WSM 180140  0.0 61.0    19  2750
```

Comment: Please include a sample of `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Try skipping the first step where you create a dataframe of years. If you group the dataframe by year and leave off the as_index argument, it will give you what you're looking for.

```
summed_df = df.groupby(['year'],as_index=False)['islam'].sum()
```

That will give you a dataframe with the year as the index. Now you just have to reset the index, and you'll have a two-column dataframe with years and the sum values.

```
summed_df = summed_df.reset_index()
```

(Note: the default for reset_index() is drop=False. The drop parameter specifies whether you discard the index values (True) or insert them as a column into the dataframe (False). You want False here to preserve those year values.)